# Most viable strategy champion 5 picks for 1v1 showdown

Tags: league-of-legends

Showdown: In the 1v1 games will be blind draft. Each player has the opportunity to ban out three champions, after which the game proceeds to a blind pick phase. After both players have locked in their picks, there will be an additional period of time in which the enemy picks are revealed to each player - this gives players a chance to adjust runes, masteries and summoner spells accordingly before the match starts. Victory can be assured by one of three ways: you can score first blood, waveclear your way to 100 CS, or demolish the enemy turret before they take down yours.

Now the strategies are:

- Keep calm, farm up
- All in for first blood
- Push the lane and tower

All of these require different champions.

What would be the most viable strategy and best 5 picks in this mode, depending on the tournaments riot organised.

Comment: Every champion who has a can push hard/has good waveclear is suited. Usually you just want to push the enemy to the tower, so you can deny him his health relic, which enables you to stay even longer in lane. Eventually he will lose cs under tower and/or has to go back through your harrass.

Answer (score 1):

If you're confident in your ability to last hit I would take a sustainable easy wave clearing champ and just go for the 100 CS or tower, since both objectives are fairly similar in how you achieve them anyways.

My reason being is that this type of play prevents the enemy from achieving all 3 of their same goals because:

- Sustain prevents the other person from killing you, unless going all in and risking their own life at the same time.
- Easy wave clears will push the lane away from your tower keeping it from taking damage
- This will also push your minions under their tower so they have a harder time farming.

Caitlyn can be a very safe champ with her huge range, Q to farm, and E to disengage from the enemy. She can take towers easily being AD but will need sustainability from items/runes/masteries.

Vladimir can be good if played well as he has very good sustainability HP wise and being manaless, wave clear, and disengage with his pool. Being AP he is better suited to farming than to push tower like Caitlyn.

These are just a couple examples but I find this type of gameplay is the safest/easiest for just about anyone to play.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is Teemo to be quite honest . Easy last hit , fair amount of poke and could easy blind the target and make them either blind shot a cs or even you . not sure if you've seen doublelift + Xpecial vs the koreans do the 2 vs 2 , but any champ with poke HAS sustain somehow.

@esq : Nice hat LOL .  Just noticed it now

Comment: example of a poking champ with sustain?

Comment: Only way to poke has to be ranged champs . I mean , it HAS to be .Jayce for example has the best poke ( even after patch 4.21 ) His gate + Q damage is still one of the strongest poke . He can farm from a decent distance and could 1 vs 1 almost, anyone at level 3 causing them to be forced out of lane . Sustain wise , , He really only needs 1 dorans blade and heal off auto's . Mana could never be a problem if you can force your opponent out of lane causing them cs + xp level.When i say sustain I meant , How long can you stay in lane than your opponent without being the first to recall .

Comment: Champs like leblanc or zed however are different. Lb can poke yes but has 0 sustain in taking damage back . Poor wave clear + mana issues and you'll be the first to recall I promise you in 6 mins. Zed can poke but he can't tale poke damage , his sustain in lane vs a jayce (example) is hardly a fight . I'm just telling you from experience .   I got rekt many times and alot of different match ups at high elo d1-master tier .If you think im wrong , feel free to point it out , i don't mind lol.I can give you more examples if you want .

Comment: you agree or naw?

Comment: you showed to different viewpoints, they are correct but all pokes dont have sustain it seems. maybe most, maybe dps ones, not bursters

Comment: I think it depends also on meele vs range or meele vs meele , You can however go maokoi , He can poke pretty hard tbh, but idk how well he will farm against an Range ap/ad user

Comment: What's more important in that situation , poke or sustain?

Comment: if you can only poke and have no sustain, maybe one misplay can lead to your defeat. but if you have some sustain, you can comeback somehow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19541/discussion-between-matt-cristao-and-esq).

Answer (score -1):

There isn't really any specific 5 that is the best champions for this.  I would say just rule of thumb, stick with someone ranged.  Ranged laners always win out in csing over melee ones.  It's just the late game is the issue, which would never get to that point in the 1v1.  Laners with really strong ranged poke and some sort of sustain are the best.  Basically, just focus on 100 csing but safely poking your opponent.  If you force them back, it can help you achieve a cs lead.  It can also force them to be risky and put themselves at risk of giving up a death.

An alternative to ranged champions, would be someone with super sustain like Yorick.  He's a complete lane bully and can still deal well with ranged poke.

Answer (score -1):

lux is the bust land your skill shots and kill Them. Also shes is very safe with her range if you want to farm. Also, you can use talon hes the easiest to first blood with just w-q Auto then ignite gg.